# Confused about the way objects are made in enums

Tags: java, class, oop, object, enums

After seeing how the compiler handles the enum's and you mentioning that the constants are instances it all made a lot more sense to me. I am however left with one more question.

```
public enum Weekday
{
  MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY
}
```

The compiler compiles it as follows;

```
class Weekday extends Enum
{
  public static final Weekday MONDAY  = new Weekday( "MONDAY",   0 );
  public static final Weekday TUESDAY = new Weekday( "TUESDAY ", 1 );
  public static final Weekday WEDNESDAY= new Weekday( "WEDNESDAY", 2 );
  public static final Weekday THURSDAY= new Weekday( "THURSDAY", 3 );
  public static final Weekday FRIDAY= new Weekday( "FRIDAY", 4 );
  public static final Weekday SATURDAY= new Weekday( "SATURDAY", 5 );
  public static final Weekday SUNDAY= new Weekday( "SUNDAY", 6 );

  private Weekday( String s, int i )
  {
    super( s, i );
  }

  //
```

In the example below I would like to explain my final question: I have seen code snippets like this:

```
enum Test 
{
  EXAMPLE1(5), EXAMPLE2(6);

  private int number;

  Test(int number) {
    this.number = number;
  }

}

Test a = Test.EXAMPLE1;
System.out.println(a) outputs EXAMPLE1
System.out.println(a.number) outputs 5;
```

Now I get confused with the outputs above when the object stored in constant EXAMPLE1 is created like so:

```
public static final Test EXAMPLE1  = new Test( "EXAMPLE1",   0 );
```

Because first of all, the compiler adds the constructor and if this constructor exists, how is the constructor I defined even invoked?

```
private Test( String s, int i )
  {
    super( s, i );
  }
```

And second of all, even if the constructor I defined is somehow invoked, how does that result in outputting EXAMPLE1 when I say System.out.println(a)? Neither the constructor I defined, nor the constructor compiler the added, add the value value EXAMPLE1 to any field of the object stored in the constant EXAMPLE1. So how is it possible that System.out.println(a) outputs EXAMPLE1? How is this value even added to the object? I cannot see any constructor adding this value to the object.

Comment: Add `private int number;` into your first example... (and a third constructor argument).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler changes your constructor from:

```
Test(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}
```

to

```
private Test(String name, int ordinal, int number) {
    super(name, ordinal);
    this.number = number;
}
```

And that's why it works.

You can verify this if you want using the `javap` tool:

```
javap -p -c -cp <directory> <package>.Test
```

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense, so the constructors are combined. But that still leaves 1 part unanswered and that is: how is it possible that System.out.println(a) outputs EXAMPLE1?